# Getting java.lang.NoSuchMethodError while using acrDeploy method in jenkins with Azure Container Service Plugin

Tags: azure, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, azure-aks

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.microsoft.jenkins.kubernetes.wrapper.KubernetesClientWrapper.getClient()Lio/kubernetes/client/ApiClient;
at com.microsoft.jenkins.acs.commands.KubernetesDeploymentCommandBase$KubernetesDeployWorker.getMasterHost(KubernetesDeploymentCommandBase.java:222)
at com.microsoft.jenkins.acs.commands.KubernetesDeploymentCommandBase$KubernetesDeployWorker.call(KubernetesDeploymentCommandBase.java:193)
at com.microsoft.jenkins.acs.commands.KubernetesDeploymentCommandBase$KubernetesDeployWorker.call(KubernetesDeploymentCommandBase.java:132)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1162)
at com.microsoft.jenkins.acs.commands.KubernetesDeploymentCommandBase.doExecute(KubernetesDeploymentCommandBase.java:78)
at com.microsoft.jenkins.acs.commands.AKSDeploymentCommand.execute(AKSDeploymentCommand.java:32)
at com.microsoft.jenkins.acs.commands.AKSDeploymentCommand.execute(AKSDeploymentCommand.java:20)
at com.microsoft.jenkins.azurecommons.command.CommandService.runCommand(CommandService.java:88)
at com.microsoft.jenkins.azurecommons.command.CommandService.execute(CommandService.java:96)
at com.microsoft.jenkins.azurecommons.command.CommandService.executeCommands(CommandService.java:75)
at com.microsoft.jenkins.azurecommons.command.BaseCommandContext.executeCommands(BaseCommandContext.java:77)
at com.microsoft.jenkins.acs.ACSDeploymentBuilder.perform(ACSDeploymentBuilder.java:56)
at com.microsoft.jenkins.acs.ACSDeploymentContext$ExecutionImpl.run(ACSDeploymentContext.java:141)
at com.microsoft.jenkins.acs.ACSDeploymentContext$ExecutionImpl.run(ACSDeploymentContext.java:125)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Finished: FAILURE
Page generated: 23-Jan-2020 16:28:06 UTCREST APIJenkins ver. 2.204.1

Comment: This is not azure problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6798767/how-to-get-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror

Comment: I think there is some problem with Azure Container Service Plugin as I haven't write any code but using that plugin only but still getting NoSuchMethodError